# Streaming audio in Flash is playing multiple times, overlapping

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio, stream

The following AS3 code is sometimes causing the audio to play multiple times, almost simultaneously like a crazy echo. It usually works ok with that URL but when I use a https://soundcloud.com url it always freaks out. On rare occasions I think the issue has happened with local files even. I copied this code from somewhere else so I don't entirely understand it. Do you see a problem with this implementation or is Flash just crazy?

```
var url:String = "http://md9.ca/portfolio/music/seaforth.mp3"; 

var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);  
var s:Sound = new Sound();  
s.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);  
s.load(request);  var song:SoundChannel = s.play();  
song.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, soundCompleteHandler);  


var time:Timer = new Timer(20);  
time.start();

function completeHandler(event:Event):void {    
  event.target.play();  
}  

function soundCompleteHandler(event:Event):void {   
  time.stop();  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `play()` twice on the `Sound` object. Once when you create the variable `song` and again when the file is done loading.

You might want to structure your code differently.

```
var url:String = "http://md9.ca/portfolio/music/seaforth.mp3"; 

var song:SoundChannel;
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);  
var s:Sound = new Sound();  
s.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete );  
s.load(request);

function onLoadComplete(event:Event):void 
{    
  song = s.play();
  song.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, soundCompleteHandler);   
  s.removeEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete );
}  

function soundCompleteHandler(event:Event):void 
{   
  trace( 'sound is complete' );  
  song.removeEventListener( Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, soundCompleteHandler );
}
```

I removed the `Timer` code as it did not do anything functional.

Comment: Thanks man, works perfect! I guess I should have seen that play thing happening twice.